# How to judge all the subprocess over in gevent?

Tags: python, subprocess, gevent

I want to Traceroute some ip in a file with gevent, here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import gevent
from gevent import subprocess
gevent.monkey.patch_thread

ip_list = open('ips.txt')
data = [i for i in ip_list]
length = len(data)

process_pool = []

for i in range(length):
  process = subprocess.Popen(['sudo','traceroute','-T', '-m', '8', data[i]], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  process_pool.append(process)

print len(process_pool)

gevent.wait(process_pool, timeout=10)

count = 0

for i in process_pool:
  if i.poll() is not None:
    count += 1
    print i.stdout.read()
  else:
    print ('job is still running')

print count
```

it works well, but I don't know how to see if all the traceroute is over, if I change the value of timeout. All the process may over, but I don't know how many ip in the file, so the code can't deal with common case. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, I just want to use gevent to see the speed of the code,so I can use the code like this, it fast enough for my job:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import gevent
from gevent import monkey, subprocess
gevent.monkey.patch_thread

all_data = []

def my_trace(ip_addr):
  process = subprocess.Popen(['sudo','traceroute','-T','-m','8', ip_addr], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  all_data.append(process.stdout.read())

ip_list = open('ips.txt')
data = [i for i in ip_list]
jobs = [gevent.spawn(my_trace, line) for line in data]
gevent.wait(jobs)

for i in all_data:
  print i

print len(all_data)
```

And, I just wait for all the traceroute end, that's all.

Comment: you could use `subprocess.check_output()` to get all output at once